# How can I fix the fact that my internet is not working without a VPN on my PC

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, internet-connection

When i don't have a VPN on, I get error on application that need internet(Error Code: -126
Failed to load web page (unknown error) (on steam).

I can still use some of them like youtube but I cannot use facebook messenger, Netflixc, steam or any other game application. When I turn my VPN on, it's working but since some app don't let you use proxy or VPN i'm getting blocked wich is anoying.

I tried changing my firewall and even reset the whole PC and it did not work.

Comment: Does your VPN have a Killswitch enabled perhaps?

Comment: no, the kill switch is off and I had this problem before installing the vpn

Answer (score 0):

To a surprise, I got same issue 2 days ago. What I checked that only websites in hosted in my country were being loaded. Youtube and google have data centers worldwide. The problem in my case was that international link of my ISP was broken and as most websites being hosted in US, my Internet stopped and google still worked.

VPN on the other hand, routes your request to some other server with different ISP and all data is routed through a working link.

Just ask your ISP if he is having problem at the back-end.

Comment: it's doing it even when i'm on a different wifi/different province and the I had this problem for over a year now

Comment: @LeCariboou Open ```ncpa.cpl``` from Windows+R. Right click on your wifi adapter, double click on TCP/IPv4 option. Make sure you have selected obtain IP automatically and Obtain DNS automatically selected. Please update.

Comment: They are both on automatic

Comment: @LeCariboou try disabling firewall for once.

Comment: does not change anything